# ASP.NET - Allowing account authentication only through web form on WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI app with Individual Accounts. Currently, I authenticate users by sending a POST request to wwww.myazurewebsite.com/Token from my app. But this means that basically anyone can send a request with their credentials and receive a token and access my controllers protected by [Authorize] attribute.

My though was to put the login form online on www.myazurewebsite.com itself and prevent outside clients logging via a simple http request. That way, I could embed the login form on my desktop app. But how do I do this?

I've seen that the Visual Studio login form and a number of websites like Twitter,Facebook... do something like this.

Comment: I wouldn't do it so simplistically, you're tying your own hands for the future. If you potentially want to allow only a small selection of pre-approved applications (web, desktop, mobile) to make requests, then you could look at how Google APIs handles this - basically you register the client application with the API and it generates a unique client key which must be used by the app when making requests to the API. Any requests not including a valid key are rejected. FWIW I think they leverage OAuth 2.0 to help with the authentication and authorisation process. Twitter etc do something similar

Comment: This then allows you to easily grant access to other apps in future (3rd party clients, or new versions of your own apps), and also gives you the potential to do things like easily collect usage stats and other metrics broken down by the different apps making them.

Comment: @ADyson The problem with using API keys is that I'll have to keep the key in my source code, and since my desktop app is written in C# anyone can access the source using Reflector and this can compromise the key. That is why I thought a online login form would work

Comment: That way, no-one else can call to /Token and get their token. They will have to go through the login form

Comment: That is a risk, yes, but it's a small one, and you could add other things to your API's armoury to protect against it, such as detecting unusual activity. If you do what you're suggesting and embed a web form into a desktop program, I think the login session context would be that of the web form, it's not clear (to me anyway) how you would then transfer that session into the context of the desktop app. Maybe there's a way. But if you're prepared to do that, ask yourself whether you really need a desktop app at all? Would the online version be sufficient?